# How can i add "view-users"-Role as a default role to newly created Users?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

i'm trying to get a list of all users in Realm in my Application.

My Question is, how i can add the *view-user* role automatically while the user is created?
The "Default Roles"-Tab are only show my normal roles.

Add the Role manually is working:
The Application is a SpringBoot-App with works as Resource Server.
(spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server)
The Client-Application does the Login and authenticats against the Backend per JWT.
So in the Backend i can use the JWT and Forward this with a call to the Keycloak "http://keycloak-url/admin/realms/%7Brealm%7D/users" endpoint.
As Result i get 401 Unauthorized - as expected.
If a add the "view-user"-Role from "realm-management" manually the user can access and gets the List.
(Keycloak 22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Realm settings` -> `User registration` -> `Assign role`

Note that if the role you want to auto-assign is defined at a client level, you should switch to `Filter by clients` (by default, only realm roles are displayed in roles assignment pop-up)

Comment: Thanks a lot man.
Filter by clients did the trick